# Return the index/position of the first digit/letter in a string in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with several columns. One of them is `df['col1']` with string values comprised of alphas, special characters (. or _) and digits. I want to create a new column that returns either index + 1 or position of the first digit or alpha.

I know this does not work, but something like:

```
df['new_col'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: re.search(r'\d', str(x))).str.startswith()
```

so that

```
col1 = abc12 returns 4, 
33zxy returns 1, 
hi_world2 returns 9
```

and so on (in case of the position of the first digit).

I also tried with find, next, and filter, but they did not work.

```
df['new_col'] = df['col1'].str.find(next(filter(str.isalpha, df['col1']))) + 1
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use re.search

```
import re
df['col1'].apply(lambda x: re.search('\d+', x).start()) + 1
```

You get

```
0    4
1    1
2    9
```

Edit: If there are no matches, re.search().start() will throw attribute error. That needs to be handled in condition. Since Pandas interpret NaN as float, the resulting position will be of float type

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['abc12', '33zxy', 'hi_world2','abc']})

df['col1'].apply(lambda x: re.search('\d+', x).start() if re.search('\d+', x) else re.search('\d+', x)) + 1

0    4.0
1    1.0
2    9.0
3    NaN
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for help! However, I get an AttributeError saying that NoneType object has no attribute 'start'. Do you know how to solve this by any chance?

Comment: Ah, didn't think of that. It works now! Thanks so much.

Comment: do you happen to know how I can get the position of the "second" uppercase letter in a string? I tried df['col2'].apply(lambda x: re.search("[A-Z]"{2}, x).span()[1] if re.search("[A-Z]"{2}, x) else re.search("[A-Z]"{2}, x)) + 1```, but it doesn't work.